# What is the idiomatic way to merge two Option instances?

Tags: enums, rust

What is the idiomatic way to merge the optional field values of two enum instances?

**Example**

```rust
enum Foo {
    Bar { a: Option<i32>, b: Option<i32> },
}

let var_1 = Foo::Bar {
    a: Some(10),
    b: None,
};

let var_2 = Foo::Bar {
    a: None,
    b: Some(5),
};

// Should result in Foo::Bar { a: Some(10), b: Some(5) }
let var_3 = /* ? */;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the [`or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.or) (and [`or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.or_else)) method is for:

```rust
let var_3 = Foo::Bar {
    a: var_1.a.or(var_2.a),
    b: var_1.b.or(var_2.b),
};
```

There is also a `xor` method if you want to get `None` when both are `Some`.